having trouble with calculating previous close for tr calculations

im trying  troubleshoot and understand why the first day[2024-03-27], is printing values for tr2 and tr3 when  it should be printing nan nan because there is not previous day for 2024-03-27

i only want it to calculate data based on days only printed


I intially though it might be something wrong with shift(-1), which there still might be. However, the calculation are correct because of it.
I also thought maybe the API is collecting more than 4 days which would could explain why there is no nan nan.
Here is a sample output using this change in the function
def calculate_tr(df):


        high_shifted, close_shifted, low_shifted = (
        df["High"].shift(),
        df["Close"].shift(),
        df["Low"].shift(),
    )

        df["tr1"] = df["High"] - df["Low"]
        df["tr2"] = (high_shifted - close_shifted).abs()
        df["tr3"] = (low_shifted - close_shifted).abs()




Date
Open
High
Low
Close
TR1
TR2
TR3




2024-04-01
5.9100
5.9400
5.5500
5.5600
0.39
0.07
0.29


2024-04-02
5.2800
5.4500
5.0900
5.3800
0.36
0.295
0.0


2024-04-03
5.2900
5.3450
5.0500
5.0500
0.295
0.53
0.17


2024-04-04
5.1400
5.8000
5.1000
5.2700
0.7
nan
nan



My orignal script:

import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time


# Calculate start and end dates for daily historical data
end_date_daily = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
start_date_daily = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=4)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Construct the API URL for daily historical data
api_url_daily = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={symbol}&apikey={API_KEY}&datatype=json&start_date={start_date_daily}&end_date={end_date_daily}'

# Fetch and process daily historical price data
response_daily = requests.get(api_url_daily)

if response_daily.status_code == 200:
    historical_data_daily = response_daily.json()['Time Series (Daily)']

    # Convert daily historical data to DataFrame
    df_daily = pd.DataFrame(historical_data_daily).T
    df_daily.index = pd.to_datetime(df_daily.index)

    # Reverse the DataFrame to have oldest data at the top
    df_daily = df_daily.sort_index(ascending=False)

    # Convert column types to float
    df_daily['High'] = df_daily['2. high'].astype(float)
    df_daily['Low'] = df_daily['3. low'].astype(float)
    df_daily['Close'] = df_daily['4. close'].astype(float)


    # Function to calculate tr1, tr2, tr3
    def calculate_tr(df):
        df['tr1'] = df['High'] - df['Low']
        df['tr2'] = abs(df['High'] - df['Close'].shift(-1))
        df['tr3'] = abs(df['Low'] - df['Close'].shift(-1))

    # Calculate tr1, tr2, tr3
    calculate_tr(df_daily)

    # Print DataFrame after calculating tr1, tr2, tr3
    print("\nDataFrame after calculating tr1, tr2, tr3:")
    print("Date       Open   High   Low    Close  TR1  TR2  TR3")
    for date in reversed(df_daily.head(4).index):
        row = df_daily.loc[date]
        tr1_rounded = round(row['tr1'], 4)
        tr2_rounded = round(row['tr2'], 4)
        tr3_rounded = round(row['tr3'], 4)
        print(f"{date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} {row['1. open']} {row['2. high']} {row['3. low']} {row['4. close']} {round(tr1_rounded, 3)} {round(tr2_rounded, 3)} {round(tr3_rounded, 3)}")

 


I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve.  Please limit your code example to the least code that illustrates your problem.  Clearly state your question, provide sample data which demonstrates the problem, show what you get and show what you expect to get.  Additionally, explain the logic of why you expect the results, and include any error messages you get.

yea sorry, first time posting on this forum, trying follow the rules best i can. im not understanding and trying to fix why the first day of the output [2024-03-27] is not printing nan nan for the tr2 and tr3 values

IIUC, you can do:
def calculate_tr(df):
    high_shifted, close_shifted, low_shifted = (
        df["High"].shift(),
        df["Close"].shift(),
        df["Low"].shift(),
    )

    df["tr1"] = df["High"] - df["Low"]
    df["tr2"] = (high_shifted - close_shifted).abs()
    df["tr3"] = (low_shifted - close_shifted).abs()


calculate_tr(df_daily)
print(df_daily)

Prints:
         Date  Open  High     Low  Close     tr1   tr2     tr3
0  2024-03-27  5.81  6.01  5.4200   5.93  0.5900   NaN     NaN
1  2024-03-28  5.94  6.32  5.8301   5.89  0.4899  0.08  0.5100
2  2024-04-01  5.91  5.94  5.5500   5.56  0.3900  0.43  0.0599
3  2024-04-02  5.28  5.45  5.0900   5.38  0.3600  0.38  0.0100


so i tried the function and its printing nan nan for the last day, and the tr2 and tr3 calcuanlation for all days are wrong because the tr2, tr3 calculation use the previous days data, and the shift(-1) did that
i try to give an output but it gives a long line of the data instead of table format

@bobmcgee Can you please update your question and put there expected output? Also the equations how you obtain the values.

i updated the original question with the new output and the function that was used

@bobmcgee Maybe I don't understand - so the table you have now in your question is your expected output?

ill try to explain better
i have 4 stocks day that print some data for each day, and in part of my script i want calculate something called True range which is TR(TR1,TR2,TR3).Now the calculations for tr2 and tr3 are suppose use the previous day close. for example if it was april 4, it would take close of april 3, and it does that for each day.
Now for first day printed(oldest to newest) (april 1st in this case), if the script worked properly, it is suppose to print tr2(nan) and tr3(nan) because it would try to look  for a previous day and notice their is not another day
